# Pursue career in Network Security

Tags: professional-education, career

My qualification is Masters in Computer Science and i am currently working as a Technical Support Associate (Network Support) with a MNC. I am good with JAVA programing and have worked on some small projects as well. I always wanted to get into security but I don't see a specific path to get into Security. I want to know if my current experience will be taken into account if I am switching into security, or do I need to get into programming for that.

I'm preparing for CCNA now and will be attempting exam within couple of months. Is there any global certification that can help me get a challenging and well paid job?

Comment: [Starting your security career – where can you go?](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/03/presentations-starting-your-security-career-where-can-you-go/)

Comment: Your current experience will always be taken into account when applying for a job, but it's not going to count much, since it's not really security related. "Security" covers a very broad range of roles which can be almost completely unrelated. Do you have anything more specific thoughts on what you'd like to do? Forensics? Vulnerability research and exploit development? Infrastructure planning? Auditing? Policy? Penetration testing? (and so on..)

Comment: Hi I am looking forward for Penetration Tesing.